# Using R to list and mark multiple csv files with characters from the title of those files, and put those in a dataframe

Tags: r, csv

I have a large number of files that are all numbered and labeled from a CTD cast. These files all contain 3 columns, for bottle number fired, Depth, and Conductivity, and 3 rows, one for each water bottle fired.

```
1,68.93,0.2123
2,14.28,0.3139
3,8.683,0.3547
```

These files are named after the cast number as such "OS1505xxx.csv", where the xxx is the cast number. I would like to take the data from multiple casts, label the data with the cast number(which I presume would go in another column for each bottle sample), and then merge that data together in one dataframe.

```
1,68.93,0.2123,001
2,14.28,0.3139,001
3,8.683,0.3547,001
1,109.5,0.2062,002
2,27.98,0.4842,002
3,5.277,0.3705,002
```

One other thing, some files only have 1 or 2 bottles fired, While others also have 4 bottles fired. I tried finding files with only 3 rows and making a list of the filenames repeated three times, and then mergeing that with the binded csv files that had three rows into a dataframe but I am very new to R and couldn't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets all of them into one data frame in order (001-100), and from there you can export it however you want.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 1))
colnames(df) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3", "file")
for(i in 1:100) {
    file_name <- paste("OS1505",as.name(sprintf("%03d", i)),".csv",sep="")
    if(file.exists(file_name)) {
        print("match found")
        df_tmp <- read.csv(file_name, header = FALSE, sep = ",",fill = TRUE)
        df_tmp$file <- sprintf("%03d", i)
        df <- rbind(df, df_tmp)
    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to add some debugging to the print("match found") or remove it. I forgot I left it in, oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
files <- list.files(pattern="OS1505")
lst <- lapply(files, read.csv)
ids <- substr(files, 7,9)
for(i in 1:length(lst)) lst[[i]][,4] <- ids[i]
do.call(rbind, lst)
#  X V1      V2  V3
#1 1  1  68.930 001
#2 2  2  14.280 001
#3 3  3   8.683 001
#4 1  1 109.500 002
#5 2  2  27.980 002
#6 3  3   5.277 002
```

We start by first creating two dummy files to try and save them as csv files to test. I named them in a way to match your files. (i.e. "OS1505001.csv"):

```
file1 <- read.table(text="
1,68.93,0.2123
2,14.28,0.3139
3,8.683,0.3547", sep=',')
file2 <- read.table(text="
1,109.5,0.2062
2,27.98,0.4842
3,5.277,0.3705", sep=',')

write.csv(file1, "OS1505001.csv")
write.csv(file2, "OS1505002.csv")
```

Going through the code, `files` checks the directory for any files that have `OS1505` in them. There are two files that match that description `"OS1505001.csv" "OS1505002.csv"`. We bring those two files into R with `read.csv`. It is wrapped in `lapply` so that the process can happen to all of the files in the `files` vector at once and saved in a list called `lst`. Now `ids` is a way to grab the id numbers from the file names. In a for loop we assign each id to the 4th column of the data frames. Lastly, `do.call` brings it all together with the `rbind` function.